# How to find how many integer values does it exit in a segment in a triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{7}\\
2.&\textrm{6}\\
3.&\textrm{5}\\
4.&\textrm{4}\\
\end{array}$

I'm totally clueless here. But from looking at the way how this question is presented. I'm feeling that it will require the use of triangle inequality. And it seems as well if the **approach of euclidean geometry is intended** then the answer will use **triangle congruence** however the given clue of $\angle \alpha < \angle \beta$ is somewhat confusing.

Can someone help me here?.

So far I have ran out of ideas. Please **include a drawing in your answer**. Can this be solved relying only in **euclidean geomtry**?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit unclear.  Do they want the number of integer values as a single answer (i.e. there are 5 possible integers) or to identify which integers from that list are possible answers (i.e. AH could be 7 or 6, but not 4 or 5)?  My calculation is that there are 5 possible integer solutions: 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.  I get these by looking at the two extremes.

1. If CMH is a right angle then \beta = \alpha.  CMH and AMH are congruent right angled triangles (by SAS).  AH therefore = 5, but this case is specifically excluded by the requirement that \beta > \alpha.
   [A=B limit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb7fM.png)
2. Otherwise, we are very constrained by the question.  HC must be 5.  HM must be 3.  CM cannot be less than 4 otherwise \beta will not be less than \alpha.  Since \beta must be greater than \alpha, H must move closer to line AC, opening up that angle.  H will move in an arc towards A keeping 5cm from C.  But as it does so, M will have to move left in order to keep HM at 3cm - so A will also move left to keep AM and CM the same.
   [H moving down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKdqK.png)
3. At the opposite limit, H will reach CM.  At this point, CM=MH+HC=3+5=8.  AM therefore also equals 8.  AH = AM + MH = 8+3=11.  But at this point, triangle CMH has disappeared, so this also cannot be a solution.
4. Between these two extremes, then, AH can be any integer value between 5 and 11.  So 6,7,8,9, or 10.  There are 5 possible integer solutions - which I assume is what option 3 means in the question.

Comment: Hi. I've read your solution but I'm still confused. If you say that $CM>4$ shouldn't this means that your solution should account for the values between those?. I mean $5,\,6,\,7,\,8,\,9,\,10$ thus being $6$? The lower bound is not very clear. Can you please help me here?.

Comment: Hi - the lower bound of 5 is covered by my point 1.  CM will be 4 when \beta = \alpha and the angle CMH is 90 degrees.  When CM is 4, AH is 5.  But this is explicitly excluded by the requirement that \beta > \alpha.  So 5 cannot be a valid integer length for AH and the first one is therefore 6.

Answer (score 0):

Since $AM=MC$ but $\angle\alpha< \angle\beta$, then $AH>HC$ independent of the length of $HM$. If the integers in the choices are the only possible answers, then the correct lengths are $6$ or $7$.